# Jetbrains / PhpStorm File Watcher with Jade / Pug

Tags: intellij-idea, pug, phpstorm, file-watcher

Install programs (I guess I did well) and my problem begins when I try to write the path for the "Program" section in the File Watcher.

Which one is the right path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It must be a part to (globally installed) Jade executable, like `C:\Users\your.name\AppData\Roaming\npm\jade.cmd` if you are on Windows or `/usr/local/bin/jade` on OSX.
Do you have Jade installed globally? Please run '`npm install jade -g`', then test jade in your system terminal by running '`jade <your jade file>.jade`'. Then specify a path to installed jade script as a 'Program' in your file watcher